# Using Google nearby places pagetoken?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a project to find counts of types (such as liquor_store or park) from the center of suburbs to analyse with crime statistics.

I've been running my API call, however, have been consistently getting a maximum of 20 results.

According to the nearby search documentation, 20 is the maximum results and a 'pagetoken' is needed to get further results.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search

I'm wondering how to loop this around to get further results so I can append more than 20 results as the maximum.

So far I've tried

```
base_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json"
search_terms = ["liquor_store", "park"]

for term in search_terms:

    for index, row in melb_suburbs_df.iterrows():
        longitude = melb_suburbs_df["lon"][index]
        latitude = melb_suburbs_df["lat"][index]
        location = f"{latitude},{longitude}"

        params = {"location": location, 
                  "radius": 1000, 
                  "types": "park",
                  "key": "[KEY HERE]"
                 }
        response = requests.get(base_url, params)
        response_json = response.json
        
        if len(response_json["results"]) == 20:
            key = response_json["next_page_token"]                    
            params = {"location": location, 
                  "radius": 1000, 
                  "types": term,
                  "key": "[KEY HERE]",
                  "pagetoken" : f"{key}"  
                 }

            melb_suburbs_df.loc[index, f"count {term}"] = len(response_json["results"]) + 20   

        try:
            melb_suburbs_df.loc[index, f"count {term}"] = len(response_json["results"])
        except:
            melb_suburbs_df.loc[index, f"count {term}"] = 0
```

How do I use the 'pagetoken' to find more than the maximum of 20 results?

I'm quite new to this and have only been coding for a couple months now. Any help would be much appreciated.